# Eclipse Plugin Project does not display Window added in Application Model

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

Looking into Eclipse 4 RCP.
Did the following:

1. Created an `Eclipse Plugin Project` (no `Rich Client` unchecked,
   `Actvator` unchecked) so no classes under `/src`
2. Created a `Product Configuration`. Application selected is
   `E4Application`
3. Created a `Feature Project` and include the plugin I created in step
   1
4. In the `.product` file I checked the configuration to be based on
   `features`. In the dependencies tab I added `org.eclipse.e4.rcp` and
   the `feature` I created in step 3 (added required dependencies as
   well)
5. Created `Application Model` with container to be the plugin project
   of step 1 and added a `New Trimmed Window`

Saved all and tried to launch an `Eclipse Application`
No window is showing up and I don't see an error in console.
Any idea what am I missing here or how is this debugged?

**Update:**
I am following: [10. Tutorial: From Plug-in to Eclipse 4 application](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html#plugin_creatinge4) 
The `10.6. Start application` is the one that fails

**Update 2:**
I noticed that some directories have been created **outside of my workspace** with the name `runtime-todo.product` (i.e. the plugin name).
Going into `runtime-todo.product\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench` and deleting the `workbench` the window showed up.
Why are these directories created outside my workspace and what was the problem here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I followed all your steps and got the expected empty window after the application started, so something is strange here.

You can try to:

- Look for an error log file in the `.metadata` folder of your runtime workspace
- Delete the file `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench\workbench.xmi`
- Add `-clean` as a program argument to your product launch configuration

Try to start the application again.

If this doesn't help, you can set a break point at `org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.loadApplicationModel` to see what happens when Eclipse tries to load your application model (see also [Eclipse 4 Source](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse4Source/article.html#source)). I hope this helps!

**[Update]:**
When you start your application, a runtime workspace is created. Here, all the meta data of your application is stored, like settings and resources. For example, in `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench\workbench.xmi` the user settings of the Application Model are stored.

Sometimes during development, this workspace can become corrupted (e.g. by stopping the application while debugging before settings are saved etc.).

You can see the location of your runtime workspace when you look into the Run Configuration of your application. In the `Main` tab you can see (and change) the workspace data location. You should keep this runtime workspace separate from your development workspace.

**[Update 2]:**
Information about the role of the `workbench.xmi` file can be found here: [Constructing the runtime application model](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse4Modularity/article.html#contributecomponents_userchanges). The web page of Lars Vogel offers a lot of useful Eclipse Tutorials at [Eclipse Plugin and Eclipse RCP Tutorials](http://www.vogella.com/eclipse.html).

The [Eclipse Help](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.use) page lets you browse the user and developer guides or search for specific topics. Information about the Eclipse launcher and thus the runtime can be found here in `Plug-in Development Environment Guide > Reference > Launchers > Eclipse Application Launcher`. Look under `Main Tab` for explanations about workspace data.

The Eclipse variables are explained in the run configuration dialog of your application. In the main tab, look for the `Variables...` button. When you select a variable, an explanation is given in the `Variable Description` field.

Comment: Thanks.None of these worked.On debugging I did not see an exception but I did see that it has return fast.Not sure where the window is supposed to be displayed from (I mean which method to locate the problem)

Comment: The `loadApplicationModel` returns a `org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.impl.ApplicationImpl` with contributor URI `platform:/plugin/com.example.e4.rcp.todo` which is my plugin project.Not sure what I am looking for here

Comment: Only I noticed is that `List<MWindow> windows = appModel.getChildren();` in `initializeServices` returns empty list.If that means something to you cause I have no idea what it means

Comment: Just Updated OP. Problem seems solved.In your step 2 were you referring to the directories outside my workspace?Why are they created?

Comment: Yes, I was referring to your runtime-todo.product directory. I updated my answer with information about the runtime workspace!

Comment: I see `${workspace_loc}/../runtime-todo.product`.Where is this variable defined?

Comment: Where are these stuff written (I mean about `workbench.xmi` or about runtime workspace)?I followed the tutorial and it was not mentioned

Comment: @user384706 I updated my answer with links to information about your questions, I hope they will be useful to you!

Answer (score 3):

You can check the **Clear** flag in your *run configuration* or specify `-clearPersistedState` in your *product definition* ... as mentioned [here in a Lars Vogel Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse3RCP/article.html#runconfiguration_problems) (search for Problem "***Application model changes are not reflected in the Eclipse 4 application***" in Table2).